# Why is my ViewBag not available in MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have an MVC website and I'm trying to set the page as active in the controller.
The result I'm getting is the `ViewBag` is greyed out with an underline. On hover, the message says:

`Unreachable code detected`

Here is my home controller

[image]

My using statements in the controller are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Comment: When you return something, you exit that method. So you exit Index() before the ViewBag is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t have code after the return statement. That makes it... unreachable.

Move the ViewBag assignment line to *before* the return View().

Comment: bloody nora you're right. Thanks. When the website will allow me, I will mark your answer as solved. Thanks!